# Issue with positioning arrow indicators at the right place

Tags: html, css

I'm tring to create and put two arrow indicators at the right and left edge of the screen, but so far I'm unable to find a solution for these two issues:

1. I can't put the arrow sign to the center of the dark container. As you can see they are outside of the container right now! (Although I used flex container with center positioning)
2. Although we can hard code the position of the elements to the edges of the screen with left property I need a proper solution to correctly position the indicators at the edges in any size of the screen.

Here is the code:

```css
.arrow-container {
  width: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 5000;
  z-index: 12;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: -22%;
  position: absolute;
}

#right-arrow {
  right: 28%;
  position: absolute;
}

.arrow-container > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3b3a3a;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0.35rem);
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 6px;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #100021) drop-shadow(1px 0.01em 1px #0d021a);
  transition: background 200ms, transform 300ms;
}

.arrow-container > div span {
  
}

.key-arrow {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
    <div id="left-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129168;</span></div>
    <div id="right-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129170;</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't set up the code snippet below [check this codepen](https://codepen.io/sayog/pen/rNWrLZQ)

Comment: @ Sayog so far the best answer... I'm still trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some css to these ID`#right-arrow,#left-arrow`

```css
.arrow-container {
  width: 100%;
  left: 25%;      
  top: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 5000;
  z-index: 12;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: -22%;
  position: absolute;
}

#right-arrow {
  right: 28%;
  position: absolute;
}

.arrow-container > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3b3a3a;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0.35rem);
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 6px;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #100021) drop-shadow(1px 0.01em 1px #0d021a);
  transition: background 200ms, transform 300ms;
}

.arrow-container > div span {
  
}

.key-arrow {
  
}
#right-arrow,#left-arrow{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
    <div id="left-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129168;</span></div>
    <div id="right-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129170;</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The vertical centering is beautifully done in your answer but the horizontal centering still is not working...

Comment: i also can't figure out that